# __isset() magic function on the Object it self

Tags: php, magic-methods

I know you can do this

```
class Object
{
    private $ar;

    public function __isset($name)
    {
        return isset($this->ar[$name]);
    }
}
```

which can then be used to do the following

```
$obj = new Object();
if (isset($obj->name)) { /* ... */ }
```

However is there a way to do this

```
$obj = new Object();
if (isset($obj)) { /* .... */ }
```

Where i can control the return of `$obj` status using the `__isset()` magic method on the object it self.

Comment: May I ask what you want to do with the isset expression? If a variable is not set, it can not be an object, so I'm just wondering for what that should have a use for you. And keep in mind that [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is not a function but a language construct.

Comment: Well it reason is, because the object is set, however there is a state which i would like the object to return `notset` however it is still initialized.

Comment: Give it a method like `public function isSet() { return (bool) $result;}`. You can just call that function and get your set status. It's a functionality of your class, not if a variable is set or not (for what `isset` is for).

Comment: That was the idea/the way it already works. I was just wondering if there was a way to do it using the magic function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could only define a new global function `myIsset()` or something like it to do this.

```
function myIsset($obj = NULL)
{
    ...
}
```

When checking the variable `$obj` with `isset` PHP doesn't interact with the object that might be referenced by the variable at all.

Comment: Yea i suppose i can do that, but its so much prettier if i do it the other way.

Comment: But that's not how it works. ;) `__isset()` is triggered in case you try to do anything with a not explicitly defined instance variable. And `$obj` doesn't qualify as such.

Comment: @Angel.King.47: Maybe if you add to your question what you actually want it for (what are you trying to achieve with that?), it's possible to suggest you something.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, because it would not make any sense (at least not in the way `isset()` is meant to be used). So `isset($obj)` is always true as long as it points to some object and not NULL/undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Magic method `__isset` is not intended to be used that way.

According to [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php):

"__isset() is triggered by calling isset() or empty() on inaccessible properties."